# CMD.exe не реагирует на Java команды (javac -version)

Tags: java, установка, sdk

[image: Пример вводимых команд]

Установил JDK 11 , прописал в переменных среды всё, что писали в инструкциях по установке java.
Перезапускал комп, не помогло.
Сталкивался кто с такой сложностью, какие ещё есть пути решения проблемы ?

Ранее стояла JDK 15 , с ней не стартовал Jenkins, удалил папку, попытался установить JDK 11.
И столкнулся с такой проблемой.

[image: Переменные среды]

Comment: в Path пропешите java_home+\bin

Comment: измените по такой формуле Path = Path + ';C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin'

Comment: https://skr.sh/s8GwDwU5XfG?a
Так должно получиться  ?

Comment: да именно так должно

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: Это паф системный? или юзера?

Comment: Не понял вопроса 

Comment: Там 2 Path. один для юзера второй для системы

Comment: Редактировал в системном

Comment: Извините тогда не имею прочих вариантов кроме того чтобы пройти по данному пути и в точности проверить на существование данной папки с файлами

Comment: Путь такой C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11, вроде самый стандартный
Прикол в том, что он даже не пишет, что такой команды нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-то похожее было, когда несколько jdk ставил.

1. удалить все jdk и все что с этим связано, **но не удалением папки**, а через панель управления (ввести **appwiz.cpl** в  коммандере либо в консоли).
   затем установить нужную
2. у меня так прописаны пути [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Действительно, удалял путём перекидывания папки в корзину. попробую через appwiz.cpl

Comment: Помогло, Спасибо!